# Where do I download linux with a specific kernel?

Tags: linux

I would like to download and install a linux version 2.6.32.24-0.2-default on vmware.  Where can I download it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel version you mention points according to google to
SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11 (x86_64) Kernel 2.6.32.24-0.2-default
You might be able to find it at the SUSE website https://www.suse.com/